# How to extract month name on a string datatype on athena

Tags: sql, presto, amazon-athena

```
SELECT sales_invoice_date,
       MONTH( DATE_TRUNC('month',
                         CASE
                           WHEN TRIM(sales_invoice_date) = '' THEN
                           DATE('1999-12-31')
                          ELSE
                           DATE_PARSE(sales_invoice_date, '%m/%d/%Y')
                         END) ) AS DT
  FROM testdata_parquet
```

I used the query above to convert the string into date and was able to get the month number on AWS athena but I wasn't able to get the corresponding month name

I have already tried `monthname` and `datename('month', ...)` but they gave the following error messages respectively:

> SYNTAX_ERROR: line 2:1: Function **monthname** not registered
>
> SYNTAX_ERROR: line 2:1: Function **datename** not registered

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Athena is currently based on Presto .172, so you should refer to https://trino.io/docs/0.172/functions/datetime.html for available functions on date/time values.

You can get month name with [`date_format()`](https://trino.io/docs/0.172/functions/datetime.html#date_format):

```
date_format(value, '%M')
```

or similarly [`format_datetime()`](https://trino.io/docs/0.172/functions/datetime.html#format_datetime).

```
format_datetime(value, 'MMM')
```

Example:

```
presto:default> SELECT date_format(current_date, '%M');
  _col0
----------
 December
(1 row)
```

(verified on Presto 327, but will work in Athena too)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `to_char()` function with `'month'` argument :

`to_char(sales_invoice_date, 'month')`

in order to return the month names.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT date_format(current_date, 'MMMM')  shows me February
SELECT date_format(current_date, 'MMM')  Feb

However, SELECT date_format(current_date, '%M') is not working for me,
its only giving me %2 only -- for February