# Problem to retrieve date and year from a json file

Tags: sql, json, date, datetime

I have a file in json, but I have trouble separating the dates in the year-month, for instance, I have in SQL (AWS)

```
SELECT json_extract_scalar(json, '$.date') Date 
FROM table_json
```

Input:

```
 Date
 ------------------------
 2016-03-08T01:28:57.546Z
 2016-03-07T05:03:58.455Z
 ....
 2016-04-07T05:03:58.455Z
 2016-04-07T05:03:58.455Z
 2016-04-08T05:03:58.455Z
 2016-05-07T05:03:58.455Z
 ...
```

and I want to have something like

```
Date
--------
2016-03
2016-04
2016-05
....
```

Comment: JSON does not have a Date/DateTime type. it's just a string, commonly stored as ISO8601.
You need to parse that into a date and extract month + year. (depends on your sql type/dialect how to do that)

Comment: [Edit] the question and tag the DBMS you're using.

Comment: Ok, I am occupying the aws amazon platform, with sql. But how can extract motn + year?

Comment: Please check if the following link answers your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59485913/how-to-extract-month-name-on-a-string-datatype-on-athena